# How to make the slicer keep highlighting the selected value even on-hover?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have Power BI slicer with the horizontal layout.

When the user makes a selection of the slicer value, then, only when the mouse pointer is taken away from the value then the value gets highlighted.

Secondly, when mouse pointer is placed on the selected value, then the highlight gets reset.

How to make the slicer keep highlighting the selected value even on-hover?

Comment: The default color of each item is white, on-hover gray and on click black, doesn't it?

Comment: Default is gray, on hover is gray, on clicking is black. But when you hover over clicked item it shows as gray

Comment: Default should be white. You may have some custom theme uploaded. Try to go to the options and change background of the values in the slicer to white. Then check again